# Can't access variable setter

Tags: java, compiler-errors, setter

im having some trouble with this code in java. So Im trying to set a boolean value from another class but im getting this error: "cannot find symbol: setCorrectA"

Class where error is showing:

```
if (isCorrect1.isSelected()) {
    a.setCorrectA = true;
} else {
    a.setCorrectA = false;
}
```

Class from where I'm trying to access variables

```
public boolean getCorrectA() {
    return correctA;
}

public void setCorrectA(boolean correctA) {
    this.correctA = correctA;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A setter is a method, you need to *call* it:

```
a.setCorrectA(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

`setCorrectA` is a method, not a data member. You need to call it with parenthesis containing its arguments:

```
if (isCorrect1.isSelected()) {
    a.setCorrectA(true);
} else {
    a.setCorrectA(false);
}
```

Note that since `isSelected()` returns a boolean itself, you can clean up this snippet an omit the if-else structure:

```
a.setCorrectA(isCorrect1.isSelected());
```

Answer (score 1):

they are methods. not properties.

```java
if (isCorrect1.isSelected()) {
                a.setCorrectA(true);
            } else {
                a.setCorrectA(false);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`setCorrectA` is a function, not a property: you have to call it like this `a.setCorrectA(true)`;

Answer (score 0):

setCorrectA() is a function which expects a boolean parameter. You can call it like this:

```
a.setCorrectA(true)
```